# Run cplex in Visual Studio but trigger a breakpoint

Tags: c, visual-studio, cplex

when I run the mathematical model I wrote in cplex in visual studio, sometimes it shows triggering a breakpoint when the cplex progress is running (searching for solutions). Critical error detected c0000374.

I can click continue, then it will execute to the end. But I don't know why this breakpoint happen.

Comment: You cannot trust the outcome of the model anymore when an error like this happens!

Comment: but i got the result and test it is correct. do you know why the stack destroy happens?

Comment: Most probably you have some mistake with memory management, arrays, etc

Comment: But I just let cplex run a model file, during which I think doesn't use arrays or pointers in the program.

Comment: I don't know why the stack is destroyed. And you don't know what impact that has on your result. You say you can _test_ whether the result is correct. Is that a deterministic, "100% sure" test? Are more than one result possible that meet the test criteria? If yes, why didn't the system, given the serious error, generate one of the other results? Which result is correct?

Comment: You should probably state the Cplex version, Visual Studio version, host OS version etc. Also 32 or 64-bit. Most likely you are doing something not quite right. Cplex is used by thousands of people and is relatively bug free.

Comment: I run CPLEX 1251 on Visual Studio 2015, 64-bit.

Comment: I know it's not a correct thing to ignore this problem, so I just want to ask how can I find where the problem is. Because there is just one line of code to do the calculation procedure, and the mathematical model is from a external txt file, I don't know why the stack can be destroyed. And it will happen once no matter how many iterations I set up.